# Is it possible to add a mp3 to a splash page?

Tags: html, mp3, splash-screen

Is there anyway to add a mp3 file to a splash page? So that it plays in the background? I've been looking around but I haven't found anything other than the embed and bgsound neither of which work for a splash page. If anyone knows anything or even a website that might be helpful would be good.

Comment: What do you mean by "splash page"?

Comment: @Pekka you know a splash screen some websites have them, you use them to tell people about the website. It also allows the person to choose whether they really want to go onto the website or not.

Comment: But how are those different from normal pages when it comes to embedding a MP3 file? Do you want playing to continue when the user navigates away from the page?

Comment: While i'm sure this is possible... Please for the love of all that is right in the world make sure you really really need this splash page. They are (with one or two exceptions) the bane of the internet browsing world..

Comment: @James Butler, yeah hahah I do, I'm building a website for a final and the group wants one so I need it.

Comment: @Pekka I only want it to play on the splash but I'll check I dont want to embed a player though.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are looking for html only solution (since you tagged only html & 'splash') then it has to be html5 as it supports audio tag.

I found this link useful for your purpose :

http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/audio/quick/

The code works for older browsers too. Though I don't think splash screens should be heavy.

Anyways, Hope that helps.